# How to send external javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ok, so this code here:

```
    var Link = "https://www.roblox.com/NewLogin"
    function Post(){
            $.get(Link,function(Data){
                    $.post(Link,{
                            "Username" : "omh",
                            "Password" : "lololololo",
                            "login" : "Log In"
                    })
            })
    }
    Post()
```

That can only be ran on https://www.roblox.com/NewLogin
How do I make it so I can run it from a .JS file on my site?

Purpose:
Just a piece of JavaScript to log into accounts. It is just for fun and to test my skills.

Comment: The [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) makes this impossible. You can turn it off in your browser for testing, if you like, but make sure not to do anything else until it’s back on.

Comment: What's stopping you from running it on your site? Have you looked at your JavaScript error console? Did you get any errors? Did you copy those error messages into a search engine?

Comment: @mini Well, that sucks.

Comment: Actually, it's a very good security feature. If this weren't the case, websites could hack your accounts on other websites.

Comment: @alex Wrong sucks. lol

Answer (score 0):

Add the following HTTP header to your server's response to the get/post queries:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

For more information: http://enable-cors.org/server.html